# Access 2013 - text search on all queries and/or all tables

Tags: ms-access-2013

In Access 2013...

1. How can I search all the queries for a particular table name?
2. How can I find all the queries that include the UPDATE command?
3. How can I search all the tables for a particular field name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should give [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408951/text-search-in-properties-access-objects) a try.  Essentially, you can export your objects into a text file, and do a search there.