# Breaking out Component VB from Access Application

Tags: vb.net, vba, ms-access

I'm looking to break my access applications out into their component pieces so that I can use some version of source control with it. I currently have separated the front end and back end database. However I would like to go one step further and separate out the front end logic in the forms into their component files. If someone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please be more specific.  Are you wanting to make standalone forms?  And or like a VB.Net app?

Comment: Access provides the [Application.SaveAsText](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6410015/77335) method which you could use to save forms as text files.  Those text files would include VBA code as well as myriad form design properties.  If you want just the forms' code, you can export the code modules as text files.  I'm unsure how to do either of those from VB.Net though.

Answer (score 0):

Access for about 20 years has supported the standard source code control interface.

The fact that the project is stored in one file is MOOT since Access can “logically” view each individual item (forms, reports, query, code etc.) as a separate object. So don’t confuse a logical view of the application vs that of physical.

There are quite a few posts on SO that outline this, and this post here gives some more information:

[Version control for VBA file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662166/version-control-for-vba-file)

When you use SCC with Access, then you see this:

if using Visual Source safe, you see this:

[image]

If using Team foundation server, you see this:
[image]

And the UI inside of Access shows the status of such objects. eg this:
[image]

There also add ins for git hub etc.

Keep in mind that Access 2010 was/is the last version to support SCC. If using 2013, then you have to use the noted "save-as-text" to send  out each part and code as a standard text file which then of course can be used by any standard source code provider/control system.